# Как описать неуправляемую структуру содержащую указатель на функцию в управляемом коде?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Нативный код:

```
typedef int (*mbedtls_entropy_f_source_ptr)(void *data, unsigned char *output, size_t len, size_t *olen);

typedef struct
{
    mbedtls_entropy_f_source_ptr    f_source;
}
mbedtls_entropy_source_state;
```

Как правильно описать подобную неуправляемую структуру в управляемом коде?

Answer (score 2):

Структуру описать очень просто: в ней всего одно поле. Я так понимаю, проблемы возникли с определением типа этого поля.

Для начала надо создать делегат и навесить на него атрибут `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`, чтобы сообщить маршалеру что этот делегат при передаче в неуправляемый код надо преобразовать в указатель на cdecl-функцию (и наоборот):

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int mbedtls_entropy_f_source_ptr(
```

Далее, первый параметр. Он является параметром типа `void*`, с описанием "Callback-specific data pointer" - то есть в нем может лежать что угодно, в зависимости от конкретного источника энтропии.

Скорее всего, его стоит объявить как `IntPtr data` - но есть и вариант рассматривать как ссылку на структуру (`ref SomeData data`).

Второй параметр играет роль массива для заполнения - массивом его и следует сделать, указав тип передачи LPArray. Также для правильного "оформления" входящего указателя как массива маршалеру понадобится длина - надо будет упомянуть что она передается в третьем параметре. Альтернативный вариант - можно принять его как `IntPtr` и работать с ним через класс [`Marshall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx).

Третий параметр имеет тип `size_t` (беззнаковое число размером с указатель) - его заменяем на `UIntPtr`.

Четвертый параметр имеет тип указателя - его можно принять как `IntPtr`. Но в соответствии с семантикой лучше указать его как `out UIntPtr`.

Вот что получилось в итоге:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int mbedtls_entropy_f_source_ptr(
    IntPtr data, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] byte[] output,
    UIntPtr len, 
    out UIntPtr olen);

struct mbedtls_entropy_source_state
{
    mbedtls_entropy_f_source_ptr f_source;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так

```
public struct mbedtls_entropy_source_state
{
    public Delegate mbedtls_entropy_f_source;
}
```